# stop a React rerender of parent component scrolling to top of page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a text area which is a separate child component of an edit form, where the user can input long text.  Above it, in the parent form, I have a SAVE button that I want to disable until the user makes an actual change to the text.  I have it triggered now that when a change is made, it calls the parent component which triggers the SAVE button to enable (shows its color).  But my problem is that it also jumps to the top of the page when it does this.  The cursor stays where the user is inputting the text, but the scrollbar jumps.  I realize that the parent is rerendering because the button has changed, but I want the scroll to stay where it is, with the cursor visible.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: A component re-rendering shouldn't change the scroll position. A render doesn't discard everything and replace it with a "new" render, rather React calculates the difference between the old DOM and the new and changes things as needed. There's probably something else going on - show us your code for the parent container.

Comment: Please provide code of your child and parent components.

Comment: Thank you Jered.  You gave me just enough of a clue that I figured out the error in my code.  I did have some old code lurking that brought the page up to the top.  Thanks for your help!